# Create a Multi Choice Text Box in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a text box or an area in my website, and I have about 9 buttons in the page which I don't want to redirect to other pages and open in the same page and in the same Text Box or The Area that I create.

So, if someone click on Button 1, then open the Text 1 with fades in animation, and when click on Button 2, Text 1 fades out and Text 2 fades in and etc. How can I do this?

Comment: None is going to give a solution. Just tell us what you have tried by providing some code.

Comment: i dont have any codes yet . i just want to make a unique website. so i have 9 buttons like Contact Us or Support or Our Project and etc. and i want when someone click on each button , a text comes up and show something about that button like Contact Us , and when click on the Our Project Button , the Contact Us Text fades out and the Our Project Text fades in

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina answered u down

Comment: @skay- answered u down

Comment: Did you make a research or you want that we do your work as your place? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply create 9 text box and 9 buttons on page load hide all text box like this

```
<input class="one" value="Text 1">
```

to hide this textbox

```
$(function(){
   $('.one').hide();
})
```

and on click of first button

```
<button class="btn1">Button 1</button>
```

show  first textbox with fadeIn animation

```
$('.btn1').click(function () {
   $('.one').fadeIn();
});
```

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/91jfvqwm/1/)

Comment: is there any way to group the buttons , instead of code .one .two .three , write .btnall , and all texts fade when click on a button and ONLY the text which is for a button fades in

Comment: @Aria what exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

i've tried this code which makes the text fades in , but i cant make it to when i click another button , the currect box fades out and new box comes in.

```css
.modalDialog {
 /*border:dotted;
 border-color:#00FF00;*/
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 500;
 /*background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);*/
 z-index: 200;
 opacity:999;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 pointer-events: none;
 position:absolute;
 width:450px;
 height:700px;
 max-height:700px;
 max-width:450px;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-left:250px;
 


}
.modalDialog:target {
 opacity:1;
 pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
 position:absolute;
 max-height:700px;
 max-width:450px;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 0px 20px 13px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 /*background: #FE9A2E;*/
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FE9A2E, #F7BE81);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FE9A2E, #F7BE81);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#FE9A2E, #F7BE81);
}

.close {
 background: #606061;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -12px;
 text-align: center;
 top: -10px;
 width: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-border-radius: 12px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }




.modalDialog2{
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 z-index: 99999;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog2:target {
 opacity:1;
 pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog2 > div {
 width: 1000px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 5% auto;
 padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: #FE9A2E;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FE9A2E, #F7BE81);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FE9A2E, #F7BE81);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(#FE9A2E, #F7BE81);
}

.close {
 background: #606061;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -12px;
 text-align: center;
 top: -10px;
 width: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-border-radius: 12px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```